# Migrating Java Web Application from MySQL to ORACLE

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, jakarta-ee, mysql-workbench

I have a Java Web Application created on `NetBeans` with a `MySQL` database so i need to migrate to `Oracle`.

- What is the best approach to migrate (creating new project, editing the mysql based project,...) ?
- What is the right way to migrate the Database(Data Transfer,Creating Tables one by one(Bad choice i think )
- What i have to change in the Configuration files?
- What is better, Editing Entity Classes in the working project based on MYSQL or Generating new Entity Classes after the migration to Oracle ?
- Any other advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't this belong to Programmers.SE?

Comment: This [does not belong to StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) ("Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar requirement in past and here is approach that we took.

1. Create a new version of application V2 few changes might be required in your entities.(assuming older version is V1)
2. Create copy of all tables in Oracle, script changes might be required.
3. Run V1 on one box with mysql and run V2 on box 2 with oracle
4. Write a utility program to export data from mysql and import into Oracle, incase data is huge utility program can do partial commits
5. Write one more utility program to compare row counts in mysql vs oracle, program can generate a report in simple text file.
6. Depending upon your application, run specific tests on box1 running V1 vs box2 running V2, to verify results.

Though this approcah was tedious but in the end we had better confidence with our testing packs that we ran on both machines and count comparison.

Depending on application you might tweak a few steps or add few more.

Hoping this helps you.

Cheers !!

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Sachin, i upvoted it while waiting another answers,if there is no more answers i will accept it!

Comment: These kind of activities involves lot of thinking process especially for the date of cutover. We migrated on a weekend as our data set was huge. Hoping you get the best answer :)